# How can I Integrate Ubuntu 32 and 64 bit into a single DVD

Tags: dvd, iso, livedvd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DVD with both 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28299/dvd-with-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-ubuntu)

I have both 32 and 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 iso, but how can I integrate them (both 32 bit and 64 bit) into a single DVD with a menu to choose from two options  Clearly written like "1. Install Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit" and "2. Install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit" and also without losing the Live Mode

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/28492/19493), it has a pretty clever way of doing it.

Comment: @Namshum: even when a question is closed answers will not be deleted and can still be upvoted. Good answers may be merged to have them **all in one place** (that's the whole point of closing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a program that will allow you to do it in Ubuntu.  But just from past exprience, I think that it can be done with scripting.  If you're not comfortable with that, pendrivelinux.com has a utility that will allow you to accomplish just that.  It called XBOOT.  Once you create the USB, you can then put it on a DVD.

> XBOOT is yet another neat little Multiboot ISO USB Creator. It is a
>   Windows based application that can be used to create a Live Multiboot
>   USB or even a Multiboot ISO file that can then be burnt to a CD/DVD.
>   XBOOT supports many Linux Distributions and Utilities, and allows you
>   to use your choice of a Grub or Syslinux bootloader. Also included is
>   a built in QEMU emulator (enabling you to boot an ISO from within
>   Windows).1

Click [to download](http://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/download)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/xboot-multiboot-iso-usb-creator/)</sup>

Comment: Will that DVD have option to boot from both OS?

Comment: According to pendrivelinux, it will have the option to boot either ISO.