# Is there a multiboot iso creator for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, iso

I want to create a multi boot CD in windows I do this with xboot but is there any program to create multi boot ISO in Ubuntu

Comment: The duplicate only talks about creating a bootable USB, and not a bootable CD/DVD.

Comment: @Mitch the accepted answer is talking about both a USB and CD/DVD.

Comment: @Alaa I know, all I'm saying, its not drag, and drop, like Yumi, and magic ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to create an Ubuntu All-in-one Live DVD uses grub4dos

http://prshah.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-create-ubuntu-all-in-one-dvd.html

Similar,but your grub configuration must match ISO you want to boot

[DVD with both 32-bit and 64-bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28299/dvd-with-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multiboot CD. you're limited to 1 ISO because of space, but you can create a multiboot USB, using [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).  Once you choose the first ISO, and its created, it will prompt you if you want to add another ISO.

[image]

I don't think that this program will allow you to create a multiboot DVD, but you can use [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/index.htm).  MagicISO has ability to create multiboot DVD image file so that the user can incorporate multiple installation CD or ISO into one DVD, and install multiple Operation System from one DVD.

Comment: OK But can I Create Multi Boot Dvd With This Program

Comment: @JohnGeorge My answer doesn't involve writing menus, just drag and drop, and you can use utilities ISO, Antivirus ISO's, and other OS as well.