# Combine Multiple ISO Files To Burn A Single Bootable ISO Image

Tags: boot, dual-boot, iso, burning

I have three ISO files : "ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso", "ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso, "ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso "  I want to combine those multiple ISO files and want to burn   a single ISO image file onto DVD that could let me use all of them. How can I do so.

Comment: You do know that 10.10 and 11.10 are not now supported? http://askubuntu.com/questions/28299/dvd-with-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-ubuntu  I prefer flash drives now as most computers support booting from flash drive unless very old.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out MultiCD. It might serve your purpose. For instructions on how to use it, check this [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/create-bootable-iso-with-multiple-linux.html) page.