# Multiple ISO in single bootable dvd

Tags: iso, livedvd

Its not just multiple Ubuntu distros in single dvd/usb as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376529/combine-multiple-iso-files-to-burn-a-single-bootable-iso-image) or Ubuntu distos with other utility ISO's in a single dvd/usb I'm asking.

I want to include Windows 7 or above version, Ubuntu iso's and utility iso such as boot-repair in a single **DVD**.

1.MultiSystem is the best tool I found but it will work only for USB.

2.MultiCd script only supports Linux distributions and not Windows.

3.Running Sardu(or any windows tools) from inside wine is not an option I'm looking for.

So is there any tool or script that could combine Windows, Ubuntu and utility disks(boot-repair) ISO's and give out either a bootable ISO or directly burn into DVD.
Thank you.

Comment: Any answer to "I want to include Windows 7" seems off topic to me. You probably will find the answer to this on http://superuser.com/ General answer: I doubt it. This is going to be a manual task with a lot of tinkering and trial and error.

Comment: @Rinzwind, I did searched in superuser, but couldn't find.The reason I asked here is I want a tool that is developed for using in linux.Anyway I'll try posting in superuser too.Thank you for your suggestion.But when usb comes to picture MultiSystem does the job well, no matter what ISO you use.Why not for DVD? Is there any way I could convert all data created by Multisystem into bootable ISO and burn it on DVD?