# How do I create a bootable multiple OS DVD in Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, dvd

I have downloaded a set of linux operating systems that include Ubuntu 15.04, Linux Mint 17, Fedora 21, ArchLinux and Bodhi linux. In totla, all sum up to a size of 4.4 gigabytes. Now what I want to do is to create a bootable dvd that would contain all these OS on it. And when I boot to the DVD, it should show me a menu for choosing the OS to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MultiCD](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/02/multicd-builds-multi-boot-cd-dvd-with.html), [SARDU](http://www.sarducd.it/downloads.html) or [Grub4dos](http://prshah.blogspot.in/2009/10/how-to-create-ubuntu-all-in-one-dvd.html). If the size of DVD doesn't allow you to put all the ISOs you want, then you can create a multiboot USB using [MultiSystem](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

Comment: I suggest flash drive, and either one of the auto tools to create it or if adventurous you can just use grub2 and copy ISO to flash drive. Then as each version gets updates you can update flash drive rather than have to create a new DVD. And flash drive can have more ISO. http://askubuntu.com/questions/388382/multi-partition-multi-os-bootable-usb/388484#388484 OLDER DVD info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28299/dvd-with-both-32-bit-and-64-bit-ubuntu  Says Hard drive, but really any drive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot