# Boot CD won't boot with a "x86-64 CPU,but only detected an i686 CPU" error

Tags: boot, kernel

The error message is

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU,but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: What kind of computer do you have?. Is it 64bits?.

Comment: It is a Compaq Presario C300. How can I find out if it is 64bit?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to have a 32 bit only cpu.  Use the i386 cd instead.

Comment: If available you can use software made for the i686 architecture which in many ways is a later and extended rendition of the earlier intel 32 bit architecture (more colloquially know as the i386). However avoid all things with explicit declaration of 64 in their specs like AMD64 which is more likely the specification of the software you are trying to implement.