# Cannot install Ubuntu in VirtualBox due to "this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot" error

Tags: virtualbox

I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox 4.2.12r84980. I see

```
this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot
```

But I am using a 64 bit Windows 8, and trying same .iso for trying Ubuntu. Then what is the problem?

Comment: Try installing the 32-bit Ubuntu ISO

Comment: It does not matter that your host system is 64bit. The whole purpose of a virtual machine is that it is a separate and autonomous machine albeit a virtual one. Edit the virtual machine configuration and change its CPU type to 64bit.

Comment: Related: [Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. How can I install Lubuntu/Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128657/kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-how-can-i-install)

Answer (score 180):

To be able to run a 64-bit OS in Virtual Box we have to make sure the virtual machine's architecture is set to 64-bit too.

- Choose Ubuntu 64-bit in *General -> Basic* settings on creation of your VM

  [image]
- In addition, for running **64-bit guests** it is recommended to enable the Input/Output APIC in the *System -> Motherboard* settings for your virtual machine:
- In the *System -> Acceleration* tab we may want to enable the hardware virtualization features VT-x/AMD-V of your CPU.
- On the host system we may have to enable [hardware virtualization in the BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox).
- In some systems a host BIOS option to prevent non-trusted execution needs to be turned off ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553469/this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu)).

Comment: For me even 'Ubuntu (64-bit)' is not listing in dropdown. All OS listing in dropdown are showing '(32-bit)'.

Comment: @ARUN had you enabled virtualization in BIOS?

Comment: @ARUN I had the same issue. While creating it, it wasn't an option but after it's created, you can go back into settings > general and it'll be in that list.

Answer (score 25):

Open the virtual machine settings. Go to the Version dropdown box (General > Basic > Version).

If you don't see "Ubuntu(64 bit)" as an option in the dropdown, it means that virtualization is not enabled on the host.

Reboot the host, go in to BIOS and enable Virtualization. Exit the BIOS, making sure you save changes.

Now, you should see all the 64 bit options in the Version dropdown box.

[image: Virtual machine general settings]

Answer (score 5):

For those of you who are like me and don't have an option on your virtual box to select the **version: Ubuntu(64 bit)**:

**Do this:** download the 32 bit Ubuntu iso. ESPECIALLY if when downloading Ubuntu on your virtual box, you chose to allocate less than 2GB of memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
vboxmanage createvm --name "ubuntu" --ostype Ubuntu_64 --register
```

or if you have already created then,

```
vboxmanage modifyvm --ostype Ubuntu_64
```

To list all the ostype: http://zeblog.co/?p=390