# This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU but detected an i686 CPU when installing on netbook with 32bit image

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Samsung N130 and I'm having some trouble.

Exact error message is

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 cpu, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

The netbook has Intel Atom CPU N270 and I used Universal-USB-Installer to boot from USB

I downloaded 13.10 desktop ubuntu 32bit got that error message.

So I downloaded 13.04 desktop ubuntu 32bit and got that message again. I'm 100% sure I downloaded 32bit

I searched but there are only help for running it on virtual machine or suggesting using 32 bit Ubuntu. Note: All downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and I chose 32 bit for both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Damn I'm an idiot haha 

I forgot to select the format option on the UUI so it left some of the x64 I installed earlier. 

I'll leave my embarrassment here in case there are people like me who make this mistake.

Note: I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question yet so I'll answer it tmr.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot install Ubuntu in VirtualBox due to "this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot" error](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to select the format option on the Ubuntu Ubiquity Installer (UUI). So it left some of the x64 from earlier installation.