# Installing ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64 on VirtualBox-4.3.2-90405-Win

Tags: installation, server, 13.10, 64-bit, virtualization

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 13.10 **AMD64 x86** (The guest) on my TOSHIBA Satellite L655D-S5109 (The host).

My/the processor is AMD Turion IIP540 Dual-Core Processor 2.40GHz **(64bit OS/x86)**
And I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.2 r90405

The problem i found is the common "*this kernel requires an **x86-64 cpu** but only detected an i686 cpu*".

Reaing on other posts in here and Stackoverflow and some other places i found out that i need the x86 virtualization ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization))

Checking the Oracle VM VirtualBox on the VM System tab, i found that **I DO** have the VT-x/AMD-V ON or activated or the checkbox checked... but i still can't install Ubuntu Server, the message still appears... what else is there to do?

Should i giveup and install a 32bit? Should the virtualization be enables on my computer (Host) BIOS or what else is there to check/verify?

Comment: Oh, and as of today November 13, the Ubuntu Server 13.10 has only the 64-bit version

Comment: You have to enable that option in your BIOS, See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation . Run "kvm-ok". If you see "KVM acceleration can be used" it is a bug with virtualbox. If you see "KVM acceleration can NOT be used", check your CPU and/or enable this option in your bios.

Comment: Thank you very much @bodhi.zazen , that did helped, i 4got to mention im using Win7 so the `kvm-ok` won'twork (I don't have *cygwin*)... but after installing [CPUID CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and checking [this](http://www.cpu-world.com/Compare/826/AMD_Turion_II_Dual-Core_Mobile_P540_vs_Intel_Pentium_4_2.4_GHz_(B80546PE0561M).html) page, and [this](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-Turion%20II%20Dual-Core%20Mobile%20P540%20-%20TMP540SGR23GM.html) one too, i've found that my processor DO have AMD-V... now i just need to find out where to activate it on the BIOS

Comment: Did you set your VM up for Ubuntu 64-bit? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/why-is-installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-my-virtualbox-4-2-not-successful

Comment: Wow.... just wow... it was just that... few hours checking if the Insydeh2o bios have an option to enable AMD-V (Which doesn't have, it looks like it's default it's enable) and the problem was just the setting 64bit on the OS in the VM... well... i sure did learn a lot about VM and virtualizacion... thanks a lot @Takkat