# Unable to boot ubuntu on a surface pro 2 with virtualbox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 64-bit

I'm trying to run Ubuntu through virtualbox. but I get this error:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

I'm on a surface pro 2. Surface Pro says it does support virtualization and it is enabled.  one thing I did notice is when Creating the virtual Machine in Virtualbox under the Version menu, it does not give me the option for Ubuntu (64-bit), only regular Ubuntu (which is x86 I suppose?) I don't understand because the surface pro 2 is 64 bit.

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

Many virtual machines and 64-bit processors can only handle 32-bit guest systems.

This may also help - [Cannot install Ubuntu in VirtualBox due to "this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu?rq=1)