# Can't boot into virtual machie

Tags: boot

Fist timer to unix/ linux operating systems. I tried to download ubuntu to use in virtual box on a windows computer. then tried to boot the machine but got an error message that says "This kernel requires an x86-64cpu but only detected an i686 cpu. unable to boot. Please use a kernel appropriate for you cpu" Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: Firstly I gather you understand the difference between an x86 Machine and 64? This also depends on what VM tool you're using. I find the easiest is VMWare Player but that's personal preference. If you've got a 64bit OS then clearly you need to download and run the 64 bit version of Linux (at least it is preferred). Once again depending on what VM you are using depends- it may only support x86 (although with that error I don't it). It's best to google that question because it isn't a "Linux question" but more issues setting up VM.

Comment: Please refer to the following link for a better answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu

Answer (score 0):

From the Virtualbox FAQ:

> Q: Does VB support 64 bit guests?
>
> > A: Support for 64 bit guests was introduced at version 2.0.0. If you wish to create 64 bit guests then we recommend that you upgrade to the latest version. Note that VirtualBox also supports 64-bit guest operating systems, under the following conditions:
> >     You need a 64-bit processor with hardware virtualization support (see User Manual chapter 1.2, Software vs. hardware virtualization (VT-x and AMD-V), page 10) and a 64-bit host operating system.
> >     NOTE: Since version 2.1.0, you can run 64 bit Guests while running a 32 bit Host. The prior requirement for Operating System is only for version 2.0.x. You still need the proper hardware.
> >     You must enable hardware virtualization through your BIOS; software virtualization is not supported for 64-bit VMs.
> >     Note: some HP BIOSES have a glitch, When You ENABLE VT-X/AMD-V, You DISABLE it, so do try both ways.

So I would try downloading 32bit ubuntu here - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.

Answer (score 0):

i686 code is intended to be executed on processors which are compatible
with the 32 bit Intel x86 platform, which includes all Intel 32bit x86
processors up to and including the Pentium 4, etc. as well as processors
from AMD and other vendors which make compatible 32bit chips. 
x86_64 code is intended to be executed on processors which are
compatible with the AMD64 64bit platform, including the AMD Athlon 64,
AMD Opteron and related AMD chip families, and the Intel EM64T based
processors. 
These 64bit processors are fully backward compatible with their 32bit
predecessors.  So if you have a 64bit AMD Athlon 64 or Intel EM64T
processor, it is up to you whether to install the 64bit x86_64 OS or
the 32bit i386/i686 OS. 
In your case your are using 32 bit Intel x86 platform, you should use an i686 kind of Ubuntu and boot your virtual machine with that.
Here is the link of the Ubuntu of your flavor: [Ubuntu 14.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=IR&version=14.10&architecture=i386)

Answer (score 0):

you are using 64 bit version boot CD/DVD/ISO. You can able to run i386 or i686 without any problem. Whatever you are ISO trying to boot, Download i386 version. You wont have problem booting

You may have to enable Virtualization tecnology from BIOS and Oracle Virtual Box to able to boot 64 bit version ISO.