# Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit

I've installed VirtualBox 5.0.14 (for Windows, 32-bit/64-bit) on a Windows 7 64-bit desktop (this is a fairly new machine which definitely has the resources to handle this). When creating a virtual machine for Ubuntu, the version tab for Ubuntu offers no 64-bit choice, only 32-bit; the developers of the Ubuntu-based software I'm hoping to use (Archivematica) recommend a 64-bit version of the OS. Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of VirtualBox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really isn't a question on Ubuntu, but if you downloaded the VB version for 32-bit systems, I'm going to guess that it will only support 32-bit OSes. See if there's a 64-bit exclusive version.

Comment: We can run 64-bit guests even if the host is a 32-bit OS what would make VirtualBox 32-bit too. We need to enable [VT-x/AMD-V in the host BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256792/how-do-i-enable-hardware-virtualization-technology-vt-x-for-use-in-virtualbox) to do so. Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu

Comment: i know how to fix this but this is not a Linux question.

Comment: @Neil then answer the question if the answer hasn't been given already and it will be moved where ever the question is more on topic.

Answer (score 0):

From [Why is VirtualBox only showing 32 bit guest versions on my 64 bit host OS](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/11/virtualbox-showing-32-bit-guest-versions-64-bit-host-os/#.VrkEgpMrLdQ) make sure that:

1. Intel Virtualization Technology and VT-d are both enabled in the BIOS
2. The Hyper-V platform is disabled in your Windows Feature list.