# How can I specifically download the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have downloaded Ubuntu 2 times for VirtualBox but in VirtualBox it just shows the 32-Bit options in the operating system menu. This is why I am assuming that the Ubuntu ISO that I downloaded was a 32-Bit version. I get a message this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot” error. That's why I want to try the 64 bit version and I do have a 64 Bit system.

Comment: The CPU on your host system has to be 64bit to run 64bit VMs. What CPU do yo have?

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/ lets you select the release, architecture and flavour of Ubuntu very easily.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/308937/cannot-install-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-due-to-this-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download all (including the 64-bit) editions of Ubuntu from : [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

Here is the direct download link for : [Ubuntu 16.04.2 desktop 64-bit edition](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) (5 years support)

Here is the direct download link for : [Ubuntu 16.10 desktop 64-bit edition](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.10/ubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64.iso) (9 months support)

Important : Make sure that the host machine on which you want to run the virtual guest system is running a 64-bit operating system that supports virtualization technology and that virtualization support is activated in the BIOS of this machine when you are using the VirtualBox application.

Updated information : The direct download links are valid only until a new (point) release will be available - **as of today (2017-02-20) these are currently Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and Ubuntu 16.10**. If one wants to download older (point) releases, they are located here : [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

Comment: If your CPU doesn't support virtualization, or it's not enabled in bios, you can't run 64 bit guests in Virtualbox .. se my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a 64 bit version on http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/

Answer (score 0):

Unless your CPU supports virtualization (Intel VT-x or AMD-v), and that is enabled in BIOS, you can't install 64bit guest OS's in Virtualbox.

To check if the cpu supports virtualization, run `cat /proc/cpuinfo| egrep "vmx|svm"` if it shows vmx or svm it is supported, and you only have to enable it in bios.