# Cent OS not supporting AMD Processor

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, amd-graphics, amd-processor

I am facing issue while installing centOS in the oracle virtual box.

The processor i am using is AMD A8, 6410.

Can you assist in the solving the issue by suggesting any lower versions of centOS which supports my processor.

The issue has been attached.

[image]

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?  All that's saying that you need to get the 32bit version of the OS instead of the 64bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. How can I install Lubuntu/Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128657/kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-how-can-i-install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mismatch of 32b & 64b versions.

Probably 2 reasons,

1. Your Processor does not support 64-bit OS, and you are trying to install 64-bit version CentOS in your virtual box[`but in your case your processor supports 64b architecture`].
2. Your HOST OS may be 32-bit, and you are trying to install 64-bit OS in virtual box.

Check the host OS is 32b or 64b, most probably if you install a 32-bit version of CentOS the problem be resolved.