# Installing Problem on XP device

Tags: system-installation

I have tried to install Ubuntu Studio both 32 and 64 versions on an old XP System several times. The installation always stopped with errors. 
With the 64 version I got the error message: "requires an x86-64 CPU; detected an i686 CPU; unable to boot". 
Does it mean there is a general Problem with the i686 CPU?
Or can I download another version to support i686 CPU?
Thanks, 
Peter

Comment: You indicate that you tried to install the 64-bit version, and of course, it fails. What happens with the 32-bit version?

Comment: Hi Peter! If it's an XP system I'd say there is no way it will be able to handle the 62bit OS. What happened when you tried the 32 bit? (Are you using 20.04? Maybe an older version of Ubuntu Studio might be better, or you could try BionicPup, which is a really light distro for old machines, and then see if you can manually install the programs you want from Ubuntu Studio?)

Comment: i686 is a type of x86 (32-bit) processor, so you cannot use a x86_64 or amd64 ISO/OS.  I get this issue on pentium M, pentium IV/4 machines as they are 32-bit only.  An older thinkpad I still use is i586 class (earlier pentium M) so won't run a modern Ubuntu at all as Ubuntu requires i686 grade.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS flavors provide x86 (i686) ISOs, eg. my thinkpad t43 runs Lubuntu 18.04 LTS...   (my thinkpad r50p i586 runs debian).  Most XP machines were amd64/x86_64 capable at the higher-end, but consumer grade often were x86 only; and Debian/Ubuntu refer to all x86 as i386 grade on ISOs

Comment: The only way to get 32bit on 18.04 other than Studio or Lubuntu was to install 16.04 and then upgrade to 18.04 for standared ubuntu.  However, **no new upgrades past 18.04 are available for 32bit x86 machines** - might be time to junk that old box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boot CD won't boot with a "x86-64 CPU,but only detected an i686 CPU" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42041/boot-cd-wont-boot-with-a-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu-error)

Answer (score 0):

i686 is a grade of x86 (32-bit) processor, so you cannot use a x86_64 or amd64 ISO/OS.

I get this issue on pentium M, pentium IV/4 machines as they are 32-bit only, but I try and boot a *amd64* ISO/OS.

*FYI: Some very early pentium M are i586 grade, ie. less capable than later model processors These won't run any modern Ubuntu ISO (but can run Debian)*.

Most XP machines were amd64/x86_64 capable, but *lower-end* (esp. older) consumer grade often were x86 only; and NOTE Debian & Ubuntu refer to all x86 ISOs as i386 grade on ISOs, so look for i386 on download (even if the code within is i586/i686 today)

Your issue is you downloaded the amd64 (64-bit x86) ISO (it's named AMD64 as AMD created the compatible x86_64, intel's IA64 was incompatible & failed in the marketplace; so even if you're using an cpu you use amd64 too).

Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS or long-term-support release, though you can add an PPA to get extended support, but you didn't provide release details. All recent 20.04 releases were amd64 (no i386 ISOs were produced after 19.04)