# Can I use the -amd64.iso CDs to install on an Intel 64-bit computer?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

I have a 64 bit Intel system, but the only iso image I can see to download is the "ubuntu-12.04-server-amd64.iso" image. Is this only for AMD processors or can I use it on my 64 bit Intel as well?