# Intel processor can use the 64-bit AMD version?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, amd-processor

I have a Intel 64-bit processor in my laptop with 8GB of RAM memory. I found somewhere that if I want to take the most out of my machine (processor and memory) I should use the 64-bit version. But, is it correct that I can use the "Desktop image for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers" (http://releases.ubuntu.com) on my machine?

> My problem / question:
>
> 64-bit AMD version for an Intel processor (Intel Core i7 2670QM)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use the AMD64 version for intel laptops. This question is answered at [Can I use the -amd64.iso CDs to install on an Intel 64-bit computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144777/can-i-use-the-amd64-iso-cds-to-install-on-an-intel-64-bit-computer)

Answer (score 8):

amd-64 means 64-bit cpu pc，both Intel and AMD