# Kubuntu downloads

Tags: 64-bit, kubuntu, kde

I downloaded two isos:

1. kubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso  Why is there no intel 64-bit choice like usual
2. kubuntu-plasma5-14.10-beta1-desktop-amd64.iso (same question)

i-386 is 32-bit right? I need 64 bit

Also is 14.1 the same as Plasma 5. Is this the same a tech preview.

Can one just install 14.1/plasma5 to hard drive and have a usable even if unstable os?

I also can't find any 13.1* intel 64-bit download sources. It also appears the only LTS 14.04 is 32-bit. How could that be?

Comment: 64 v amd64 explained: http://askubuntu.com/questions/512966/64-v-amd64-distribution, 64-bit Intel machine can use the AMD64-bit?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285358/64-bit-intel-machine-can-use-the-amd64-bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the 64-Bit version of Ubuntu only compatible with AMD CPUs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197001/is-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-only-compatible-with-amd-cpus)

Answer (score 1):

**Kubuntu**

Main page: http://www.kubuntu.org

Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu

Download: http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu

There are 32 bit and 64 bit...[image]

The kubuntu-plasma5-14.10-beta1 is: http://www.kubuntu.org/news/14.10-beta-1

> Plasma 5 a work in progress. The next generation of KDE Software is
>   still a work in progress. You can test it and install it from the
>   Kubuntu Plasma 5 image but beware it will remove your stable software.

The Kubuntu 14.10 will be released: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseSchedule

> October 23rd

Naminig of the Ubuntus: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

> The official name of an Ubuntu release is "Ubuntu X.YY" with X
>   representing the year (minus 2000) and YY representing the month of
>   eventual release within in that year.

**Q**

> I also can't find any 13.1*

**A**

The 13.10 support has been ended: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2014-July/002598.html

Releases: http://releases.ubuntu.com

Kubuntu 13.10: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/13.10/release/