# Can Cinnamon run on an intel 12th gen I7-12700H processor with ARC A770M graphics w/16GB GDDR6 Ram?

Tags: cinnamon

So bought a new bare bones Intel system and decided I want to try Unbutu Cinnamon as I have been a windows person forever but grow weary of all the hickups and monetary tracking......  When I go to download cinnamon, all I see is references to AMD, not Intel processors?  Can I run this on my machine?

Comment: Argh.. pasted the wrong link. Meant to close to [Can I use the -amd64.iso CDs to install on an Intel 64-bit computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/144777/158442)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your processor is definitely supported.

The regular 64-bit processors are called `amd64` because AMD introduced the technology before Intel. All modern Intel and AMD 64 bit processors are termed as `amd64`.