# Are 64-bit and 32-bit versions included in the same ISO?

Tags: installation, release-management

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Does Ubuntu now release 64-bit and 32-bit under the same ISO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are separate images.  You should select the version that you want from the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  On the page you linked to, amd64 denotes the iso for 64bit, and those with i386 are 32 bit iso files.

You should also get the [md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) for the iso that you download and check that is correct before burning the image to a CD/DVD or USB stick.

If you have an unreliable internet connection then you might want to get the files from one of the official [BitTorrent downloads](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads) because it will have extra error checking and the ability to recover and restart.

Comment: Thanks. But how come the directory doesn't list 64-bit for i386? Only AMD64 arch.

Comment: See my amended reply.  The i386 files *are* the 32 bit iso's. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64

Comment: thanks. I think that kind of naming convention is awkward.

Comment: Have a chat with Intel and AMD about that one :-)  These are their names for the 32bit and 64bit command sets respectively.

Comment: @fabricator4 haha Thanks for the note :))))