# Where can I download Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS desktop edition for 64 bit?

Tags: installation, 64-bit

I am unable to find the link to download 64 bit Ubuntu version 10.04.4 for Intel based processor.

Answer (score 8):

This is the [link containing all the different images for Ubuntu 10.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/). Don't get confused with the naming of [`AMD64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) - this is the name of the Architecture - doesn't mean you have to have an "AMD Processor".

Direct Links for Desktop images of Ubuntu 10.04.4:

- [Standard Download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)
- [BitTorrent Download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

---

Linked Question:

- [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

Comment: Thanx Aditya, This cleared my confusion. My company uses 10.04 as standard environment but, thanx for suggestion