# Choosing 64 bit Ubuntu on Universal USB installer

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I would like to create an USB Live and I have intel processor which supports 64 bit systems but I dont know which version of Ubuntu best is  for me..actually I have downloaded an Ubuntu iso file which is called "ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" but the word amd in the name made me confused.I dont remember which link I used .

I will use Universal USB installer so if I choose Ubuntu 12.04 desktop , how can I make sure that I am going to download 64 bit version of it?

and i386 means 64 bit?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you intel processor can handle 64bit then the "ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso"  is fine.

AMD is probably only used as they were the original 64bit processors

https://askubuntu.com/a/54298/32548 can provide more info