# Is there a 64-bit version for Intel systems?

Tags: 64-bit

I am downloading the 64 bit version, but the tar file is labeled amd64.tar.xz...will this work on mhy intel 64 system, or should I just use the 32bit version?

Comment: The `amd64` version works on 64-bit Intel processors as well as 64-bit AMD processors. See [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64) (We can close this as a duplicate of that question.) If you're *installing* Ubuntu itself, though, then you will usually not be downloading a `.tar.xz` file; instead, you would download a `.iso` file. (See [these installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) and [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328).

Answer (score 2):

`amd64` is equivalent to `x86_64`, is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set. Intel called it Intel64 initially.

Different distros use different naming, a bit confusing but in fact they are the same thing. Debian uses `amd64` (that's why Ubuntu uses the same) while Fedora, Arch Linux use `x86_64`. Don't worry;-)