# Version of Ubuntu for Fujitsu AH502 Lifebook?

Tags: 13.04

I have recently placed an online order for [Fujitsu Lifebook AH502](http://www.fujitsu.com/fts/products/computing/pc/notebooks-tablets/all-round/lifebook-ah502/)

The laptop is yet to be delivered.
I was about to download 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04, thinking that my laptop is 64 bit.

But this is AMD version. Does it make difference (that my laptop will be Intel)?

OR should I download 32 bit version? Will it work better on my machine?
Is there any other variant of Ubuntu that will work better on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

To answer in short: AMD64 (aka x86_64) refers to 64-bit architecture used by AMD as well as Intel (and VIA and few others too). It's called AMD64 *only* because AMD was first to come up with a 64-bit CPU architecture.
Similarly, Intel x86 refers to 32-bit implementations of Intel & AMD equally.

What it implies for you: You **can** (and should) use the 64-bit version you downloaded even if the machine's using an Intel CPU. I'm using the same version on an Intel laptop.

For further info: [check this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Comment: Thanks. I will install AMD64.

Read these articles afterwards.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit
http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64
http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Comment: That'd be good. :-)

Answer (score 0):

AMD is a x64bit architecture, so you definitely should download the 64bit version. However, in terms of the operation system version itself, if you really dig for the more improved and advanced features Ubuntu has to offer, just wait 90 more hours (4 days) for [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com) 13.10. Its coming out on Thursday, October 17th. I assure you, from using the final beta release, its really worth the wait