# 64 bit ubuntu studio version for intel pc

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, intel

Is the "ubuntustudio-12.04.3-dvd-i386.iso" file 64 bit or 32 bit? If I have to download 64 bit version for my Intel PC (which has a 64 bit processor), which one should I download?

Comment: This link: [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64) solves it.. if you need a 64 bit version, it's amd64 that you're looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for 64bit (AMD) download and you can install in intel also

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

All Intel Core 2 Duo and Intel Core i3, i5 and i7 support either 32 Bit or 64 bit. You will not have a problem with this. With what you might have a problem is with the amount of memory you need. For 32 Bit the minimum for a good running system is 512MB, the maximum is 4GB. For 64Bit the minimum recommended is 2GB and the maximum is "let your imagination fly!!!". I have tested 64Bit versions on 1GB and they can run very slow sometimes. The more memory the better.

If your Core 2 Duo laptop has at least 4 GB of ram I would recommend 64 bit but since it is a laptop and the more memory you have in a 64 bit the better, I would recommend sticking with the 32 Bit version. You actually don't loose to try both but for your case I would go more with the 32 Bit version (Except if it is some kind of 4GB+ Ram Laptop).

Answer (score 0):

32 and 64 bit go with several different names, listed below:

#### 32 bit

```
i386
i586
i686
x86
```

#### 64 bit

```
amd64
x86_64
```

---

So, to answer your question, "ubuntustudio-12.04.3-dvd-i386.iso" is 32 bit because it has `i386` in it.

To download the 64 bit version, get a .iso file with one of the 64 bit names in its filename.