# Installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my new laptop, but when I download 64 bit desktop version. from Ubuntu site the ISO file is "ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64",
is that OK? I have Intel i-7 processor.

Comment: Yes that is the right one!

Comment: Visit [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64) to learn more about the differences between i386 and amd64 or x86_64 intel cpu architecture. it is sort of funny answer too because the guy asking the question wanted to know if he can install amd64 image on his amd computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. All new Intel and AMD processors suppot the AMD64 instruction set. Generally AMD64 just means 64 bit and will work on any modern processor.