# How to find 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 on this webpage?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

Sorry for such a simple question.

I want to install 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 on Intel PC.

At this link, http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ various download links for ISO files are available.

I have a small confusion in the two links as shown below.

1. ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso
2. ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

Question 1 : Which one of this is a 32 bit OS and 64 bit OS ?

Question 2 : Is the second link only for AMD processor based CPU's ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64)

Answer (score 1):

1. ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso — 32-bit architecture
2. ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso — 64-bit architecture

Both Intel and AMD processors are supported by both .iso files.

<sub>**Reference:** [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)</sub>