# I can't install .deb-packages

Tags: software-installation, 64-bit, deb, opera

When I'm trying to install Opera browser, it just tells me that amd64 is the wrong architecture. What does that mean? WHat can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64/144782#144782

Answer (score 1):

There isn't Opera 32 bits for linux. Only 64 bits, an you machine seems to be a 32 bit one... You may try another web browser. Or install a old version of Opera form [here](http://www.opera.com/download/get/?id=35885&location=360&nothanks=yes&sub=marine)