# VirtualBox Manager says "Ubuntu (64-bit)" while OS prompt says 32-bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

My VirtualBox Manager says my OS is 64-bit. The command prompt says otherwise, however, and "About This Computer" confirms it's 32-bit. I wanted to go 64-bit all the way and I have no idea how this happened. Should I have selected the AMD 64-bit version despite having Intel Windows 7 64-bit?

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you probably chose to install 64bit but selected the image of 32bit version. check the platform using uname -a

Answer (score 2):

The OS shown in VirtualBox Manager is the OS that is chosen [when the VM is created](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-create-vm.html). This only affects [some other settings](https://superuser.com/q/617272/309562) and will not necessarily match the OS that is later installed on that VM.

The output of `getconf LONG_BIT` is [not a good way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10137880/3511560) to check whether your OS is 32-bit or 64-bit. [A better way](https://askubuntu.com/q/41332/15341) is to use `uname -a`, which will show whether you are running the 32-bit (i386) or 64-bit (x86_64) kernel.

You mentioned that you did not choose the AMD 64-bit version. That is the version that you need for 64-bit, and will run on both Intel and AMD processors that support 64-bit. See the following for more info: 
[Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54296/15341)