# unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, 16.04

I had installed Ubuntu 15.04 in the past alongside Windows by disabling secure boot and UEFI. Then I got dissatisfied by Ubuntu performance. I decided to remove Ubuntu, deleted most of the stuff. After that, whenever I went to boot menu, it still had two options below Windows, of Ubuntu hdd2 and Ubuntu hdd3. I didn't bother about it.

After the release of Ubuntu 16.04, I want to install Ubuntu again.
After successful installation of Ubuntu, it says restart. When I restart, then by default Windows loads, so I have to go to the boot menu and select Ubuntu hdd2 or Ubuntu hdd3. Then it shows me grub 2.02  console.

Methods I have tried:

- disabling all the secure boot stuff again
- using easeus software
- trying various Linux commands on the grub console screen.

Also, I didn't get the option while installation in Ubuntu to "install alongside windows" so I had to use those partition.

Now I really want to install Ubuntu. Help! :)

**edit it worked like a charm , look at PCP answer below :),
16.04 is looking amazing....better than windows 8 and 10 **

Comment: EDIT: I am using an intel processor and have a 64 bit system, but ubuntu 16.04 is available in 32bit for intel and 64 bit for amd, so I had to install ubuntu 32 bit

Comment: amd64 is 64-bit for both Intel and AMD. See http://askubuntu.com/a/54298/158442

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting it: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your windows 7/8/10 machine.
2. Un-Allocate some space e.g 100 GB by deleting some partition.
3. Now reboot your system with bootable usb/CD of ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

It will automatically detect the unallocated space and will get installed their without disturbing your other systems.

Note: Ubuntu 16.04 Beta release contains may bugs. I will advice to install security update daily.

Comment: let me try that ,,, thanks for taking time to write anyways :)

Comment: but a problem is , in the previous version ubuntu used to show me a menu , to select between windows and ubuntu , but now by default it opens ubuntu, A possible workaround is just pressing f12 and selecting windows in boot option, nevertheless  thanks ,  maybe this is an error in the beta version :)

Comment: If it helps, plz upvote answer.

Comment: hmm it says 15 reps needed upvote your answer .. maybe i need few more reps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install  **windows** and **ubuntu**, you can use bellow way

`windows` in `UEFI`

and

`ubuntu` in `legacy`

then after, you want log in windows go to selection option in BIOS and you select **UEFI** for **windows** login and you selected **legacy** for **ubuntu** login then after u can use that way.

**Important** :- most using **os** must be install as **UEFI**.

Comment: I have this option in bios , select mode : uefi / legacy ,now when i change it to legacy, the system gives me PXE rom error,

Comment: did u install below two os in those option ?

Comment: @ThilinaSampath can u plz explain technicalities  installing one os in UEFI and other is Legacy.

Comment: @paperbuntu :- The message Exiting PXE Boot ROM, when starting up a system, means that the system tried to load an Operating System from its network card, rather than from the hard drive. ... Use the arrow keys to navigate Boot or Advanced BIOS features. Refer to on screen instructions to set the first device to IDE0, Hard Disk or SATA0

Comment: @PrakashPandey :- Legacy Boot is the boot process used by BIOS firmware. The firmware maintains a list of installed storage devices that may be bootable (Floppy Disk Drives, Hard Disk Drives etc...) and enumerates them in a configurable order of priority.
UEFI boot is the boot process used by UEFI firmware. The firmware maintains a list of valid boot volumes called EFI Service Partitions. During the POST procedure the UEFI firmware scans all of the bootable storage devices that are connected to the system for a valid GUID Partition Table (GPT).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling fastboot (if enabled) ? It's under your power saving settings in control panel Win7. Win10, it's buried in with screensaver settings I believe. I used to have dual booting issues, disabling fast boot option corrected the issue. Just a thought.

Comment: yupp I did everything, But now I have installed ubuntu 16.04 from PCP 's answer, but the problem is ubuntu is too much buggy , it disconnects wifi and many times just the process goes into preemptive scheduling...as a result my laptop hangs and , the capslock key has a led , which starts to blink continuously until I Force switch the laptop off....