# How to get the right ubuntu download?

Tags: downloads, iso

I'm trying to get my iso ready for my newbuild that doesn't have an o/s, but can't find the right download for my new processor.

When I download from my old computer the file name includes the processor (AMD 64) on this computer, which, I don't think would work on the new one (i7) I want it for.

How can I find the right one, please? Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64) helps you.

Comment: check this website http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/

Answer (score 4):

For Intel processors (i7) AMD64 and i386 are suitable.

AMD64 stands for 64 bits architectures and i386 for 32 bits ones.

Please double check it but I pretty sure you have to download AMD64 Ubuntu image (64 bits)

Hope it helps

Comment: @nefilim20 - Consider accepting it then.