# Can I still get Ubuntu after my first download attempt fails?

Tags: system-installation, downloads, donation

I paid $15.00 US and the download failed at approximately 300 megabytes, what do I do now?

I don't know what else I can contribute here -- it failed.

Comment: You don't need to contribute, that's optional, but I'm sure appreciated by Canonical.  You should be able to retry the download but this time skip the contribution.

Comment: where did you download it from? Ubuntu is free you don't have to pay for Ubuntu everytime you download it but you can always *donate* use [this link](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) to download an official *.iso* image. If you had issues with donloading or connectivity you should consult with your internet provider but Ubuntu has nothing to do with that.

Comment: You can also resume the download process if you still have the partially downloaded file and its source URL. Most web browsers can do that out of the box upon instruction but a download manager may help if this happens frequently.

Answer (score 37):

As others have said, you don't have to pay to download Ubuntu -- the donation is optional. Therefore **you can simply download Ubuntu again** however you like. There's no need for you to donate again, just as there was no need for you to donate in the first place.

(I hope you weren't misled into thinking otherwise! It's great to donate, but everyone should be aware that Ubuntu is available officially and at no charge.)

Currently, the donation page gives you the opportunity to  direct funds toward particular goals in Ubuntu development. So if you want to do that,  that's one benefit of donating. However, donating *doesn't* enable you to download Ubuntu *faster*. Everyone should be able to download Ubuntu pretty fast, whether or not they donate (and no matter how much they donate, if they choose to do so), and **everyone has all the same download options**. So the second time you try to download Ubuntu will be no less likely to succeed than the first.

Sometimes your own Internet connection might have problems that interfere with reliable downloading. If your download is getting interrupted, is slow, or the file you get at the end is corrupted (broken), then [**as Peyto says**](https://askubuntu.com/a/871692/22949) you will likely be best off downloading Ubuntu [with the BitTorrent protocol](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

However, if you want to just try downloading Ubuntu again from your web browser, you can skip the donation page by clicking **Not now, take me to the download!** This is what the donation prompt currently looks like:

[image: Donation prompt shown when people download Ubuntu in the usual way through the website, showing a visible Not now, take me to the download! link at the lower-left corner.]

You can also, if you like, go directly to [the main download server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) and use the links from there. For example, [you can get Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/). You'll most likely want the [64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) or the [32-bit PC (i386) desktop image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso). (Which one you should choose *doesn't* depend on whether your processor is made by Intel or AMD; [the 64-bit release works on both 64-bit Intel and 64-bit AMD processors](https://askubuntu.com/a/54298/22949).)

Once you've downloaded Ubuntu, I suggest [checking its MD5 hash to see if the file really downloaded successfully](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). This can save you some hassle -- it's better to find out your download was bad *before* you install than *during* installation.

- This may be unnecessary if you're using [BitTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent), since that protocol [automatically checks](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38646/10251) that what you've downloaded is correct, and your BitTorrent program will [redownload any pieces of the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Creating_and_publishing_torrents) that are wrong. (This is very convenient and is one of the reasons to use BitTorrent to download Ubuntu, especially on an unreliable Internet connection. See also [Peyto's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/871692/22949).)
- But for downloads over the web, especially if your Internet connection is unreliable, it's a good idea to check the downloaded ISO image before you do anything with it.
- [If you're currently running Windows, this section is for you.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows)

If you're unsure what to do once you've successfully downloaded your Ubuntu ISO image, see:

- How to put it on a USB stick, from [Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), [macOS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos), or [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).
- *Or*, how to put it on a DVD, from [Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), [macOS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-macos), or [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu).
- [Try Ubuntu before you install it](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) (once it's on a USB stick or DVD).
- [Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) (once it's on a USB stick or DVD).

Comment: To be fair, the layout of that screen (and the "Pay" label on the button) seem quite misleading to me. I hope that hasn't led this OP to have "paid" when they might otherwise have not donated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - It is confusing but that is called "marketing".

Comment: @MichaelKaras: There are laws about misleading marketing that make you think you have to pay when actually you don't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I agree with you but it is still someone's idea of marketing persuasion.

Comment: @MichaelKaras: Of course; what else would it be? That's exactly my concern.

Answer (score 8):

You can download Ubuntu and not get charged any money.

Since I'm guessing that your Internet connection is slow I would personally recommend the torrent download. It is a bit better at not stopping or getting interrupted. Just go to https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and click [alternative downloads and torrents](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). Then go under the bit torrent section and download whatever you would like.

Or if you wouldn't like to deal with torrents, click *Download* instead and move all of the sliders to the far left so as to not donate any more. (Or you can click, "Not now, take me to the download.")

Comment: If you put the partial download in the exact location the torrent will download to it should even be possible for it to take advantage of those parts you already have.

Comment: Yes, I agree with kasperd. Many torrent clients also let you specify to add a torrent based on an existing (partial) file.