# where do I download ubuntu desktop for intel?

Tags: intel, downloads

When I download ubuntu, it always gives me an image for amd...

Like ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Where can I find an download for Intel?

I try to install that through Oracle VirtualBox so maybe I am doing something wrong in the virtual machine I create...

Comment: "it always gives me an image for amd" No, well not if you mean the company there. https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64

Answer (score 12):

This is for Intel too. The amd64 mean that this image is for 64-bit architecture.

On below link you have direct links to downland with information aobut images:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/

Of corse you can download all releases from this link too:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Wow.. I didn't know that.