# Question about epson printers under 16.04 xenial

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, epson, lsb-release

How can I install the driver for my Epson WF-2830 printer on Ubuntu 16.04?

I know this has been discussed in numerous posts from 2013 thru 2018.  Most of them seem to revolve around tricking the OS into loading an LSB package from an earlier Ubuntu release.  I have spent hours trying several of them, without success.  Does anyone know:

1. Was there ever a final resolution?
2. Where can I find it?

After doing `sudo apt install -f`

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.5-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386.
(Reading database ... 261831 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.5-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (1.7.5-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 depends on lsb (>= 3.2).

dpkg: error processing package epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386
```

Output of `uname -a`

```
Linux phil-ThinkPad-linux 4.15.0-66-generic #75~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 14:01:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Reason for using 386 version of driver, the only 64 bit version is AMD, and I was unsure if this would work on Intel.

Comment: What is the problem? Download and install the driver from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule I am using this driver on 16.04 with no problem at all.

Comment: I downloaded WF-2830 Series
 Printer Driver  Linux 1.7.5  ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)  All language 11-01-2019.  dpkg complains about missing LSB >=3.2.  Installing LSB does not fix it.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` and all missing packages will be installed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new information instead of posting it to comments.

Comment: Is your system 32-bit? Please add output of `uname -a` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install a wrong driver. `i386` is intended for 32-bit systems, you have a 64-bit system.

The problem can be fixed this way:

1. Remove the wrong driver

   ```
   sudo apt purge epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386
   ```
2. Download the `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.5-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` file.
3. Install it using `dpkg -i`.

All should work.

Regarding `amd64` and Intel CPU see [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54296/167850)

All packages installed in your system are `amd64` except some specifically intended for 32-bit processes.

Comment: So AMD64 will work on x86-64.  Never knew that.    Trying it...

Comment: See the question statement.  This answer resolved the problem I was having installing the driver.

Comment: Just click the check sign at the left of the answer to accept it. The "thanks" in the question is better to be removed.