# newbie preinstall question

Tags: dual-boot

I want to install Ubuntu on my Win10 Intel machine, but I noticed the file I downloaded is ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso. Is this .iso file for AMD processors only? If yes, where I can get .iso for Intel processors?

Thanks,

zb

Comment: No. AMD is not the BRAND AMD but the 64-bit architecture. i386 is 32-bit. Burn the ISO to a stick/dvd/bd and boot from it Oh and this has your answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Answer (score 0):

In short: that's the correct iso file you have downloaded. It will also work for intel!

In computer world people call 64bit as amd64 and 32bit as i386. If your aim is installing 64bit ubuntu then you need to install amd64.iso. Actually, Ubuntu does not provide 32bit version for ubuntu 22.