# 32bit vs 64bit on desktop

Tags: 64-bit, desktop-environments, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

My cpu is Intel® Core™2 Quad Q8200 which, by Intel page support 64bit.
I went to the download section and saw that for desktop Ubuntu recommends the 32 bit and not the 64 bit.

1. Why? I know that there were problems with flash and Java on older versions - but is there any reason I should not go on 64 bit version?
2. Why does the 64 bit version called amd64 and not just 64bit, I always thought that the AMD relates to AMD the chip manufacturer and can't understand if it compatible to Intel chips