# What version of Ubuntu 11.10 should I prefer? 64bit or 32bit?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, dell, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

#### My notebook Configuration:

**Model:** Dell N4110
**Processor:** 2nd Generation Intel® Core™ i3-2310M processor 2.10 GHz
**RAM:** 4GB

As far as I know, some software do not support 64 bit OS. What about this?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple 'rule of thumb' is that if you have >=4Gb RAM and a 64-bit capable processor then you should install 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 11.10 has multiarch support and you shouldn't really have a problem running into software that won't work under 64-bit. I'd recommend the 64-bit variety so you can get the most out of your hardware.

Answer (score 2):

install 64 bit version and use this command to install 32 bit libraries,so that you dont have any problem running 32bit software..

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Newegg.com, the specs for your Dell laptop look just fine (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834200286&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-NA-_-NA). You have Windows 7 Home Premium as your operating system (which is a 64-bit OS), so I can't see why you would have any problems with installing either one. Just make sure that Dell's hardware meets the system requirements to install Ubuntu 11.10 (again, this will most likely turn out to be not a problem for you). I run Ubuntu 11.10 (32-bit) on my ASUS Eee PC netbook (has 2GB RAM), and it is working just fine. If it works well on a netbook, then it will work on a laptop.

I hope I answered your question accurately! =)

Answer (score -1):

32 bit will do for,why there is need of 64 bit,How can you say that hardware is 64 bit compatible

Comment: The [specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/52220) for the processor indicate that it is indeed 64-bit, although you are right that you could still run a 32-bit OS on it.

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit depend on processor.

Comment: Right, but the processor the OP has *is* a 64-bit processor. Therefore, he could run either a 32-bit or 64-bit OS on there just fine. If it was a 32-bit processor, then he could only run a 32-bit OS, but that is not the case.

Comment: OP's processor is 64bit. Just in plain