# which version of ubuntu should I install?

Tags: installation, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32bit and 64 bit and which should I chose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-chose)

Hej,
I am about to install ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop:
http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/dell-studio-s15z-2249cpn/4507-3121_7-33974716.html?tag=mncol;subnav
I am not familiar with ubuntu and this is the first time for me using it.
first of all, 32 or 64 bit?

moreover, after installing it, what should i do?
Do i need to install any driver?

thank you for any answer!!

/matteo

Answer (score 4):

I advice you to install Ubuntu 11.10 64bits. You'll get the most from your computer.
Installing additional drivers is very easy and will be automatically proposed after the installation if it is necessary. If you are used to Windows, Ubuntu should seem far easier on that point.

If you encounter any other problem in the future, feel free to ask here on Ask Ubuntu !

Comment: Very kind and very quick in your replies, thank so much to both of you!
I will give a try with 11.10 64bits

Comment: PLease consider upvoting @RubenBakker 's or my answer and/or marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, the laptop seems capable of handling 64-bit, so I recommend using any 64-bit version that suits your needs.

Now, Ubuntu currently has 2 widely supported versions: 11.10 and 10.04. both are about to be replaced by 12.04. But if you want the transition to 12.04 to be smooth, I highly recommend you use the 11.10 version.

If you want the most stable environment for your laptop, assuming you'll be doing all sorts of crazy stuff on it, use 10.04. But 11.10 is stable enough for laptops and I've used it for my own laptop for months now without unintentional mess-ups.

So yeah, I recommend 11.10. I couldn't find any specific details on your laptop regarding Ubuntu, so that's kind of disappointing. But I'll just assume it'll run well. Dell is known to run well with Linux, as far as I know.