# Should I install 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between 32bit and 64 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit)

My computer is a gateway nv55s17 with a 64 bit processor. The ubuntu website said 32 bit recommended so i dunno which to pick

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/7034/18612

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have an x64 processor then you should choose an x64 operating system.