# 32-bit or 64-bit for a Intel Celeron 2.93Ghz processor?

Tags: 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32bit and 64 bit and which should I chose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-chose)

I read somewhere that Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit is recommended by Canonical.. but my machine is not AMD64.. So which one should I prefer? 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: can you post here the results from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/932190/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cpu is 32-bit. Use the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a 64-bit machine then the i386 (32-bit) image is the one for you...

Also going by your answer you say it's not AMD64 (an actual AMD processor) which is fine, AMD64 images will run on 64-bit Intel processors as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a 64-bit Intel processor then I would highly suggest using the AMD64 images(these will still work), as some applications are only available to run on 64bit machines.  Oracle 11g for example.