# Which version of Ubuntu 12.04 should I go for? 32bit or 64 bit?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32bit and 64 bit and which should I chose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-chose)

This question may have been asked infinite times but i want to know in my specific case that if i am using 2GB ram and a Core2Duo processor which one will give better results? I have already used 11.10 64bit version on  virtualbox on my laptop, but it really won't tell that if 64 bit is faster than 32 bit(though technically it is). Found many threads regarding confusion between 32 and 64 bit, but not a case like mine. Please help me out with this.