# Is 12.04 compatible with the Athlon XP-M processor?

Tags: 12.04

Having tried on an off for several days on and off to install 12.04 unsuccessfully I today actually got a useful message during installation when it froze "stopping CPU interrupts balancing daemon" There the system froze. The processor is a 32 bit AMD Athlon XP-M in an Asus Laptop. Looking at the versions of 12.04 available for download I notice that AMD64 processors need different downloads to Intel processors and have different checksums.

Need some expert advice here? Is 12.04 a non starter so far as my particular processor is concerned or will the AMD64 (which is presumably designed for a 64 bit work? Does anyone know?

Comment: Consider reading this [Which version of Ubuntu 12.04 should I go for? 32bit or 64 bit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124318/which-version-of-ubuntu-12-04-should-i-go-for-32bit-or-64-bit?rq=1) /// and the rest of the Related questions --->

Answer (score 1):

- The Athlon XP-M is a pretty old CPU and while it supports [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAE), the rest of the system (motherboard, etc.) may not.
- Ubuntu 12.04 has a PAE-only kernel; please try installing Xubuntu 12.04 or Lubuntu 12.04 instead.

Answer (score 0):

That processor is supported by the 32-bit version of Ubuntu. But if it booted at all, you are already using the 32-bit version of Ubuntu, so this is a differn't issue you are having. :/