# When to use 64 bit version?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32bit and 64 bit and which should I chose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-chose)

I have a Duo Core processor with 4 Gb Ram.
Should I use the 64 bit version for Ubuntu 12.04?