# 32-bit Ubuntu Vs 64-bit Ubuntu dual boot with windows 7 32-bit?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, intel, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

I have Intel DH55TC motherboard with Intel i3 530.
I have 4GB RAM.
Suggest me correct version of Ubuntu to use.
whether 32 bit or 64 bit is suitable for me.