# Intel i7 7320QM 64 or 32 Bit?

Tags: intel, architecture, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Well, I've recently bought an Alienware M17X and it has and Intel processor, which I've never had before.
My last computer had an AMD processor,which ran only Ubuntu 64 Bit. I had installed Ubuntu 32 Bit first, but I had lots of problems, and one of them was the machine temperature, that gets lot hotter when running a 32 Bit version.
My new processor is an Intel 7320QM and it runs Windows 7 64 Bit fine. But like my older machine used to run Windows Vista 32 Bit fine, but not Ubuntu 32 Bit. It doesn't make sense at all.
So I need to know if one of you guys have ever experienced something like this befor? Which version should I get for my Intel processor, 32 or 64 Bit?

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on how much RAM you have. If you have more then 4 GB of RAM, and if it's Alienware, I'm assuming you do, then you should definitely install Ubuntu 64 Bit to take advantage of all of that RAM.

Comment: But it won't be raising the temrature will it? Can Intel processors handle 64 Bit systems? Because I downloaded the 64 Bit version and the name of the file already comes with "amd".

Comment: It doesn't depend on how much RAM you have and much less the Manufacturer of the Computer, you can perfectly use the 32 bit with over 4GB of RAM. @ThiG. Intel CPUs handle 64 system since.. like 15 years ago, now in regards of the 32 vs 64 bit pros and cons *And* the amd suffix in the ISO images there are already answered questions here, please make use of the search field up there.

Comment: if it is duplicate, then point our mates to the duplicated one. be nice!