# Should I upgrade to 64 bit Ubuntu with an old laptop model?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 64-bit, 32-bit

I just realized, and I mean it literally just a few minutes ago, that my processor Intel T5870 supports 64-bit. I have had this laptop (ThinkPad R61i) for two years mainly running Ubuntu 32-bit. So far I haven't had a problem with it until last week when my OS (12.04) crashed due to a bad software update (my guess).

Should I take advantage of my processor's capability and upgrade to 64-bit (and I know I would have to reformat my laptop completely for it) or just let it run with 32-bit without my laptop's performance suffering for using a higher end OS?

I have a 3.9GB memory, integrated graphics, and 130GB hard drive.

Comment: you should go for 64 bit os

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should!  Using the amd64 edition of Ubuntu will allow you to use the full bandwidth of your processor and system bus.  If you need to run 32-bit software on a 64-bit install of Ubuntu, things are easier now that 12.04 supports multi-arch.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 64-bit is greater than 32-bit on your computer. It is new enough.

Comment: Thank you, Linux Distance. But is my 3.9gb enough to use a 64-bit without hassle?

Comment: Yes, of course. Windows 7 64-bit cannot run with <2GB RAM, but Ubuntu can :)