# Does the AMD Sempron 140 CPU support 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Few days earlier I had completely shifted to Ubuntu ( frm windows). I had downloaded a 64-bit version, But I think mine pc will not support it.. It is installed and working properly.

Mine specs is as follows:

AMD sempron 140
1 Gb ram (here is da problem :( )
320GB sata

So should I install a 32-bit version or I should carry on with current one?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall with the 32-bit one.

32-bit Ubuntu: Works on both 32-bit and 64-bit Systems.  Some features (like more RAM) on a 64-bit system will be restricted if you use 32-bit Ubuntu.

64-bit Ubuntu: Only works on 64-bit Systems and will not work with 32-bit Systems.   Use this only if you are sure that you are using a 64-bit system.

Comment: Thankx for the answer :) I am using a 64-bit system but mine RAM is low.. only 1gb

Comment: Then use the 32-bit system.  Its risk of messing up is lower.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter anything whether he is using 32bit OS or 64bit OS. If his ram is low what can be risk of creating  mess?

Comment: I also have a 64-bit System but I use 32-bit Ubuntu because I heard somewhere else that 64-bit systems are more unstable.

Comment: "Some features (like more RAM) on a 64-bit system will be restricted if you use 32-bit Ubuntu.", no not anymore PAE is default now so now you can have more RAM while in the 32bit version. And it doesn't matter if you have 1Gb ram that doesn’t mean the 64bit version won't work, it works the same as long as the CPU supports it. And no it's not unstable is the *same*. you can get a better explanation in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you now what OS type (32 or 64 bit) you are using? If you are using a more modern computer (Windows 7 is a good example) you are most likely using 64 bit Windows. If you are in doubt, and have only 4 GB ram MAX, then get the 32 bit version.