# I try to install 32 bit OS, but last two times 64bit OS only got loaded? Why?

Tags: 32-bit

And I am using Windows OS 7 of 32 bit operation. All my windows application are suitable for 32 bit only. Example I would like to use MS Office Excel & Word as it is while in Ubuntu OS. But may be since my application in 32bit and Ubuntu in 64bit, i am not able to open it completely. So I would like to use 32bit Ubuntu, otherwise 64bit is very fine for me. I use Wine application.

(1) Is it mandatory to have only 32bit ubuntu for the ms office which i installed in my windows 7, 32 bit os?

(2) Why even if I choose 32 bit ubuntu installation, it's always downloading amd64.tar.xz?

Regards,
Saravanakumar T

Comment: iirc wine is 32 bit only by default anyway.  you don't need 32-bit ubuntu.  also iirc there is a wine64 package

Answer (score 0):

To learn more about 32/64 bit systems read the information on this question https://askubuntu.com/a/70551/71679

As to your second question "why is it only downloading the amd64 version" after a quick look, if you are trying to download the 32bit version from here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop the link appears to be broken thus why you can only get the 64bit version. So if keen on using the 32bit version you can download a copy from here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/daily-live/current/ and get the PC (Intel x86) desktop CD version