# HELP! i cant run the machine!

Tags: kernel, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

when i try to run the machine a messeage appear in the black screen sayinh 
"this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, buy only detected in a i686 CPU. Unable to boot please use a kernel appropiate for your CPU"

i'll aprecciate

Comment: Hello. Please provide enough information about your problem, what did you do and in which step did this happen. It seems that you are trying to install the 64 bit version in a 32 bit based hardware but you don't tell us. Please edit your question and add as much useful information you can. Oh! Yeah, and welcome to AskUbuntu. Your question has already been voted to close by other users. Good luck!

Comment: How did you try to run? If it is a Live CD or USB, I think, you downloaded 64bit version instead of 32bit version which is supported by your CPU. Please, download the 32bit version. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&release=lts&bits=32) is the link for 32bit Desktop edition of 12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

Check some possible reasons:

- Hard disk moved in another computer or updated motherboard/cpu
- grub pointing to wrong kernel
- you are trying to run from wrong ubuntu cd image

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to run the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on a 32-bit machine. You are probably attempting to boot from a live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive. If so, you'll need to download the correct ISO image (the one with `i386` rather than `amd64` in its name), and burn a new CD/DVD or write the new image to the USB flash drive.

If this is happening on an installed system, that's somewhat strange. As [Beernarrd](https://askubuntu.com/users/41678/beernarrd) has [said](https://askubuntu.com/a/181942/22949), it's possible that you are trying to boot an Ubuntu system from a hard drive that was moved to a 32-bit machine from a 64-bit machine. It's also *possible* you've replaced your 64-bit CPU with a 32-bit CPU, but that's also pretty unlikely--these days, there aren't that many motherboards that take both 32-bit and 64-bit CPU's. (Also, if you had just replaced your CPU, you would probably have told us about that in your question...)

I don't think it's particularly plausible that this could be caused by GRUB pointing to the wrong kernel. 64-bit kernels are extremely unlikely to be installed on a 32-bit system. If you had done that, you would probably know about it. It's not the sort of thing you can usually do by accident.

To reiterate: If this is happening when you're trying to use a live CD/DVD/USB, the problem is that your machine has a 32-bit processor but you used the 64-bit `.iso` image (with `amd64` in its name) rather than the 32-bit `.iso` image (with `i386` in its name).