# Need more RAM?? Running VMmachine + ubuntu

Tags: performance, vmware, ram

So I looked but im running ubuntu in vm machine and its running at a snails pace and I installed the 64bit ver. Running windows 7 64bit the down side is that I only have 2GB of ram installed.....bummer huh I know the answer is im going to need more ram I just want to confirm... Or is there an tip that I can do change some settings to make it run faster in VM? I just want verification on what steps I can take if any to speed things up?

Thanks Experts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need more RAM :)

You can try 32-bit version of Ubuntu in the VM (and, as a matter of fact, running 64-bit Win7 on 2Gb of RAM [is not totally justified too](http://blog.tune-up.com/windows-insights/32-bit-vs-64-bit-more-bit-more-performance/), but it may be more difiicult to reinstall) See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70551/14564) for fancy graphs.

You can also try a lighter variety of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

You can also try allocating more RAM to your VM, 1Gb being a reasonable minimum.

Comment: Im going to try to install the 32bit ver on VM, Have not had any issues with Win 7 on 2GB RAM yet but ill be upping it to 4GB with in the next couple of weeks.  I have other systems and they run at 8-16GB RAM...but this one im on here is my test pc so I use it for testing and learning. Thanks for all the help!